# Run Athena Query via CDK

Tags: amazon-athena, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a table in Athena using the AWS CDK in C#. As my table needs to contain `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES` (and I cannot see how to add them when using `aws-glue-alpha.Table`), I have opted to create the table via an Athena query in the CDK.

I have tried using both `CfnNamedQuery` (which creates a saved query but does not run it) and `AthenaStartQueryExecution` (which does not every show up in CloudFormation).

Here is how they are defined:

```
     var cfnNamedQuery = new CfnNamedQuery(this, "MyCfnNamedQuery", new CfnNamedQueryProps {
       Database = DatabaseName,
         QueryString = @ "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE " + Database.DatabaseName + @ ".workflow(
       `instructionid`
       string
       ROW FORMAT SERDE
         'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
       STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
         'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
       OUTPUTFORMAT
         'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
       LOCATION
         's3://bucket/workflow'
       TBLPROPERTIES(
         'has_encrypted_data' = 'false'
       );
       "
     });
```

```
      var startQueryExecutionJob = new AthenaStartQueryExecution(this, "AthenaStartQuery", new AthenaStartQueryExecutionProps {
        QueryString = @"CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE " + DatabaseName + @".workflow(
        `instructionid`
        string) 
        ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
        STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
        OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
        LOCATION 's3://bucket/workflow'
        TBLPROPERTIES(
        'has_encrypted_data' = 'false'
        );
        ",
        IntegrationPattern = IntegrationPattern.RUN_JOB,
        WorkGroup = "primary",
        ResultConfiguration = new ResultConfiguration {
          OutputLocation = new Location {
            BucketName = "mw-query-results-dev",
            ObjectKey = "myprefix"
          }
        },
        QueryExecutionContext = new QueryExecutionContext {
          DatabaseName = DatabaseName
        }
      });
```

I am ideally looking for an answer to one of the three following questions:

1. How can I add `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES` when creating a table using `aws-glue-alpha.Table`?
2. How can I execute a saved query?
3. How do I correctly use `AthenaStartQueryExecution`?

Comment: What is the [CloudFormation AWS::Glue::Table equivalent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-table.html) of the properties you want to set?  Perhaps `AWS::Glue::Table SerdeInfo` [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-table-serdeinfo.html)?